# (Sed) Search/Replace Involving Negative Number Yields Extra Characters

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I'm using `sed` to look in a text file and replace any values that match `999` with `-999`.

The problem I'm having is that the command is inserting WAY too many extra negative symbols...

**Code:**

```
sed -i "s/999/-999/g" /home/weather/data/.../master_tmp
```

**Result:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------999
```

**Expected Result:**

```
-999
```

Comment: post your input file also

Comment: i tried the exact same command (v.4.2.2 on Fedora 22) and it works like charm. are you sure that this effect is not because of multiple runs. e.g. from `999` -> `-999` -> `--999` -> `---999` ...? since you are editing the file inplace

Comment: VTC because it can no longer be reproduced or is a simple typographical error

Comment: that's not possible. you're running the command in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I had the sed command in a `while/do/done` loop...